# Error: - StaticInjectorError(AppModule) - ngx-bootstrap-product-tour

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My goal is to implement [this](https://nmilicic.github.io/ngx-bootstrap-product-tour/) (it isn't a requirement using this code).

After trying to implement it, i get the following error:

```
AppComponent.html:15 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule) NgxBootstrapProductTourService -> Router]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgxBootstrapProductTourService -> Router]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

I think the error comes from using the selector:

```
<ngx-bootstrap-product-tour></ngx-bootstrap-product-tour>
```

*With this I am unable to achieve my goal...*

**How can i achieve my goal?** Answers containing a better solution/better api or something available for angular6 that I can directly integrate it in my app are going to be considered.

Comment: Facing same issue